# Mysql stopped working on my wordpress website

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm not that experienced with linux or mysql so bear that in mind.

I generated my website using the wordpress droplet on digital ocean and its been working fine, but today the website started saying
`Error establishing a database connection`.

So I power cycled the server and it didn't fix it.

Next I went into the ssh console and used the command `service mysql status`

It said:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm)
    Process: 1790 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1809 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 25 (limit: 1131)
     Memory: 627.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─1809 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Which I think means that it exited while trying to start up.

The error log says:

```
2023-05-21T00:40:44.983416Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-05-21T00:40:45.837488Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 3348299
2023-05-21T00:40:45.849124Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-05-21T00:40:57.249705Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-05-21T00:44:48.871761Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80032' to '80033' started.
2023-05-21T00:49:24.748818Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'ALTER TABLE user MODIFY ssl_type enum('','ANY','X509', 'SPECIFIED') NOT NULL; ' failed with error code = 3664, error >
2023-05-21T00:49:24.770070Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2023-05-21T00:49:24.770938Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-05-21T00:49:25.380870Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-05-21T00:49:26.329708Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 3348366
2023-05-21T00:49:26.340737Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-05-21T00:49:37.907861Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-05-21T00:53:45.694567Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80032' to '80033' started.
```

So I assume that its trying to upgrade the server and failing every time.

I tried to do it manually, but whenever I use `service mysql stop`.

It just hangs there indefinitely.

When I try to connect to the service with `mysql -u root`
It says:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I tried stopping the processes using:

```
sudo pkill mysql
sudo pkill mysql
sudo killall mysql
sudo killall mysqld
```

But they still appear in the list when I use `htop` so I assume its not working.

I tried using `killall -9 -r "mysqld"` and it may have worked. I also selected the mysql process in `htop` and pressed f9+enter to send the kill signal to that process.

Next I used the command: `ps aux | grep mysql`
Which returned:

```
root        2555  0.0  0.0   8160   724 pts/1    S+   09:57   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Which makes me think all the mysql processes are now dead.

When I try to start the service again with: `sudo service mysql start --skip-grant-tables`

It hangs for over a minute and says:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` file does not exist, but `/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock` and `/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock` does.

Error log:

```
0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 2781
1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80032' to '80033' started.
4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'ALTER TABLE user MODIFY ssl_type enum('','ANY','X509', 'SPECIFIED') NOT NULL; ' failed with error code = 3664, error message = 'Failed to delete SDI 'mysql.user' in tablespace 'mysql'.'.
0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

How can I get mysql working again so my wordpress website can work?

Comment: What version of MySQL were upgrading _from_?

Comment: @RickJames the crash log says `Server upgrade from '80032' to '80033' started.` so I think its 8.0.32 to 8.0.33. I didn't manually tell it to update, so it might be from a forced wordpress update somehow.